# Третья строчка при наведении на Donut Chart в Apexcharts

Tags: javascript, диаграммы

Хочу добавить третью строчку при наведении на данные в Donut chart в библиотеке Apexcharts. У меня сейчас при наведении отображается название сегмента и его данные, хотелось бы добавить третьей строчкой еще одни данные, но нигде нету инфы как это можно сделать. Единственное что нашел это в форматоре возвращать массив `formatter: (val) => [val, data]`, но данные просто перечисляются через запятую. [image: Donut chart]